# can't have email on existing user golang

Tags: postgresql, go, authentication, web

I'm trying to check if an user already have a email. I wrote a function like this :

```
func IsUniqueEmail(body io.ReadCloser) (database.User, error) {
connection := database.GetDatabase()
defer database.CloseDatabase(connection)

var user database.User
err := json.NewDecoder(body).Decode(&user)
if err != nil {
    return user, err
}
var dbuser database.User
connection.Where("email = ?", user.Email).First(&dbuser)
fmt.Println("User: ", dbuser)
fmt.Println("User: ", dbuser.Email)
return dbuser, nil}
```

but the fmt.Println show me

> User:  {{0 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC }    }

I assume where is no email in dbuser but I can't understand why
anyone have an idea ?
Cheers

Comment: Can you share more details about how your database is structured, how fields are mapped? Also instead of printing multiple lines, you can do `fmt.Println("%+V", dbuser)`. It will print fieldnames along with their values.

Comment: okay thx for the answer.

My user

```type User struct {
 gorm.Model
 Name     string `json:"name"`
 Email    string `gorm:"unique" json:"email"`
 Password string `json:"password"`
 Role     string `json:"role"`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gorm v2, you can catch the record not found error

```
var dbuser database.User
err := connection.Where("email = ?", user.Email).First(&dbuser).Error

if errors.Is(err, gorm.ErrRecordNotFound) {
        return dbuser, err
    }
fmt.Println("User: ", dbuser)
fmt.Println("User: ", dbuser.Email)
return dbuser, nil}
```

Comment: Thank for the answer. It's seems he didn't find the user but in database he exist

Comment: I found the solution.
thx to both of you

Answer (score 0):

The solution

```
func IsUniqueEmail(body io.ReadCloser) (database.User, bool, error) {
var dbuser database.User

connection := database.GetDatabase()
defer database.CloseDatabase(connection)

var user database.User
err := json.NewDecoder(body).Decode(&user)
if err != nil {
    return user, false, err
}
errDB := connection.Where("email = ?", user.Email).First(&dbuser).Error
if errors.Is(errDB, gorm.ErrRecordNotFound) {
    return dbuser, true, errDB
}
if dbuser.Email != "" {
    return dbuser, false, nil
}
return user, true, nil
}
```